# Get data from google sheet in JSON format using sheet ID - android

Tags: java, android, json, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I am able to retrieve sheet data(specific column) in JSON format using script. But i want to retrieve sheet data(specific column) in JSON format just entering sheet ID in my android app Edittext.

Suppose, i enter any sheet id in my app edittext and want to get those sheet data(specific column) in json format.

Sheet Link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AtYF5g2_A3AiAhejVj595bDLxO1zoGq7PNGjbdV9U8Q/edit?usp=sharing

**This is how i retrieve data using script:**

```
public void getAllData(){
    String urls = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbw2hRTBRJk_UngIxZVNz1p4CMfZe2aJfyK3on3WyTZo1hVszSWu63DP/exec?action=getItems";
    String json_string;
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    Request request=new Request.Builder().url(urls).build();
    client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
            if(response.isSuccessful()){
                final String str = response.body().string();
                MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        json_string=str;
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
}
```

**App script that i used for this:**

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AtYF5g2_A3AiAhejVj595bDLxO1zoGq7PNGjbdV9U8Q/edit#gid=0");
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("CSE522");

function doGet(e){
  var action=e.parameter.action;
  if(action=='getItems'){
    return getItems(e);
  }
}

function getItems(e){
  var records={};
  var rows = 
sheet.getRange(2,1,sheet.getLastRow()-1,sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
      data=[];
  for(var r=0, l=rows.length; r<l; r++){
    var row = rows[r],
        record = {};
    record['ClassDate']=row[0];
    record['Umail']=row[1];
    record['Subject-Code']=row[2];
    data.push(record);
  }
  records.items=data;
  var result=JSON.stringify(records);
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(result).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
}
```

**But i want to get this way:**

```
public void getSheetData(){
    String strSheetID = editText.getText().toString();
    //now i want to here - using strSheetID get json data for specific column
}
```

Please solve my problem and take millions of thanks.

Comment: So, you are currently getting your desired data by making a request to an Apps Script web app, and you'd like to get rid of this? You could get your data directly from Sheets API, using [spreadsheets.values.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/get). See [this](https://developers.google.com/workspace/guides/android) and [this](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/java) for more details on how to authenticate and get the data.

Comment: But how to get these data in JSON format @Iamblichus

Comment: Well, the API response will be data in JSON format (see [ValueRange](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values#ValueRange)). Exactly, how would you want the data to be structured in the JSON?

Comment: I want to get exactly [this](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbw2hRTBRJk_UngIxZVNz1p4CMfZe2aJfyK3on3WyTZo1hVszSWu63DP/exec?action=getItems) format. @Iamblichus

Comment: Not sure what this data corresponds to. Can you provide the code related to the Apps Script web app you're currently accessing?

Comment: I update app script. please check it. @Iamblichus

Comment: I think your question is too broad, considering that you have yet to go through authentication to the API. I'd suggest you to start by checking the links I provided and connect to the API, and then this more specific issue can be tackled.

Comment: I am able to parse JSON data from "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1AtYF5g2_A3AiAhejVj595bDLxO1zoGq7PNGjbdV9U8Q/od6/public/values?alt=json" this way. Is there any similar way to get all the sheet tab name? @Iamblichus